# Get the Information Management Policy schedule

Tags: information-management

I know the `stsadm -o setpolicyschedule` command, but I have to get/read the current schedule instead of changing it. Is there a stsadm command or PowerShell cmdlet I can use? Or another way to see which schedule is set for the Information Management Policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see Information management policy timer job and set schedule for it.

In order to do this, please do the following steps:

1. Log in to **Central Administration**
2. Click **Monitoring** > **Review job definitions** (under **Timer Jobs**)
3. Click **Information management policy** timer job
4. In **Recurring Schedule** settings, you can set schedule for this timer job.